# How to add methods/modules access control in Daemons?

Tags: ruby, daemons

I want disable the `rm\_rf` method of the `FileUtils` module in Ruby scripts.

When `foo.rb` contains:

```
FileUtils.rm_rf(file)
```

It should not be run by:

```
Daemons.run("foo.rb", some_options)
```

and should give an error message instead.

Does `Daemons` can do this? Or can some other libraries can do this simply and effectively?

Comment: You don't need a library, just redefine it to a no-op.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can I have an allow-list, then disable all other methods of all modules?

Comment: Sure; get all the methods, reject those in your list, redefine the remaining.

Comment: @DaveNewton Much appreciate if you can give me a guide on this!

Comment: Implemented one way (roughly) as pseudo-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rough outline of what you want to do.

Using `alias_method` is likely not a good idea unless you define the old method to something else; here methods are defined away. The danger of this approach is that internal behavior may be affected in anticipated ways, e.g., an allowed method uses a disallowed method internally.

The following is for singleton (class) methods, the same logic may be used for instance methods. There are *several* ways this could be implemented, this is just one, meant as a guide.

```
> FileUtils.pwd
=> "/home/dave"
> FileUtils.cp '.bashrc', 'tmpbashrc'
=> nil
> class Object
*   def deimplement_singleton_methods *methods
*     methods.each do |msym|
*       define_singleton_method msym do |*args|
*         raise NotImplementedError.new "#{msym} not implemented"
*       end
*     end
*   end
* end
> FileUtils.deimplement_singleton_methods :cp
> FileUtils.pwd
=> "/home/dave"
> FileUtils.cp '.bashrc', 'tmpbashrc'
NotImplementedError: cp not implemented
from (pry):10:in `block (2 levels) in deimplement_singleton_methods'
```

There's also [Module::undef_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/undef_method) and [Module::remove_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/remove_method), which may or may not provide the behavior you want (not sure what you need it to do).